# TFS Create global Queries

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have several Projects and at each project I need some queries. The queries are always the same except for the **Team Project**. Is there a way to create a global query that I can acces from all projects and that shows only the project related *Work Items*?

I tried to create a Query and mark it as *Overall projects query* (sorry if this is the wrong translation I have only the German UI and there it is called *Projektübergreifende Abfrage*)

When I execute the query and check the box it shows me all *Working Items* of all projects but when I create a criterion and set it to **Team Project** with the value **@Project** and then execute it, the criterion disappears.

Comment: I tried to create a new Query with "Query across projects" checkbox ticked, the query returned me the Items for all projects. The moment i create a new clause and added Team Project and in the value added a project name the query returns correctly but the query removes the clause and also removes the tick mark as you have mentioned. I believe this is because the moment we add a clause to have the query return value for one project it becomes a normal query for that particular project. This happens if u only select the current prjct name as the value of the clause Team Project. wrks fine 4 othr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query can return results from multiple team projects, but still have to be "saved" under a specific team project (so access cannot be global across all team projects). That means you would have to create a copy of the query in each team projects using the generic Team Project = @Project criterion.